# What does “=1.0 was unexpected at this time” mean in Jboss EAP server

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-eap-6

I recently faced this issue while trying to run Jboss EAP server using `standalone.bat` in a windows environment.
I faced the error below in the command window:

```
=1.0 was unexpected at this time.
```

Can you help me on this?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context? It looks similar to: https://support.software.dell.com/fr-fr/stat/kb/74858

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to make it easier to understand so people can help you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to look into standalone.bat file to fix this issue. The issue is with below command which is in *standalone.conf.bat*,

```
if not "x%JAVA_OPTS%" == "x" (
  echo "JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values: %JAVA_OPTS%"
  goto JAVA_OPTS_SET
)
```

I removed entire statement with below one and it seems working fine for me,

```
set JAVA_OPTS=
 if "x%JAVA_OPTS%" == "x-Xrs" goto JAVA_OPTS_SET_RS
 if not "x%JAVA_OPTS%" == "x" goto JAVA_OPTS_SET
 :JAVA_OPTS_SET_RS
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open up the run.conf.bat. Locate this section:

   if "x%JAVA_OPTS%" == "x-Xrs" goto JAVA_OPTS_SET_RS

   if not "x%JAVA_OPTS%" == "x" goto JAVA_OPTS_SET

   :JAVA_OPTS_SET_RS
2. Here is what to add

   set JAVA_OPTS=

   if "x%JAVA_OPTS%" == "x-Xrs" goto JAVA_OPTS_SET_RS

   if not "x%JAVA_OPTS%" == "x" goto JAVA_OPTS_SET

   :JAVA_OPTS_SET_RS
3. Save the run.conf.bat